# Replace special character with lapply and gsub in rstudio

Tags: r, regex, lapply, gsub

I am trying to clean up my data by applying the following codes:

```
Manuf <- lapply(Manuf, gsub, pattern ='%', replacement ='')
Manuf <- lapply(Manuf, gsub, pattern='\\$', replacement ='')
```

I noticed the moment I applied the code, it turned my data into values. (from data with 366 observation with 14 variables, to values of list of 14).This caused a problem when I applied this code to designate columns to from characters to numeric.

```
Manuf[, c(4:7,13:14)] <- sapply(Manuf[, c(4:7,13:14)], as.numeric)
```

It returned an error of "incorrect number of dimensions"
How do I avoid my database from changing to List when replacing the character?
Any suggestions?

Comment: `Manuf[] <- lapply(Manuf, gsub, pattern = '[$%]',  replacement ="")`?

Comment: Sorry, I figure out what went wrong, I left out [] after database, the correct code should be database[] <-lapply (database, gsub, pattern, replacement)

Comment: Thank you @WiktorStribiżew!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
Manuf[] <- lapply(Manuf, gsub, pattern = '[$%]', replacement ="")
```

The `[$%]` pattern will remove both `$` and `%` symbols from the data frame.